# How does chrome cancel the optimization of inactive tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, puppeteer, chrome-remote-debugging

When chrome opens an A website and immediately switches to another tab, the resources of the A website will be optimized by chrome, including iframe loading, images loading, timer optimization, request optimization, etc.

I want to know how to turn off this optimization because I am doing a test-like job and he needs to open multiple tabs at the same time. However, we found that the tab resource in the inactive state is limited.

The range I can do is to increase the chrome startup parameters, call the chrome extension api, use `chrome remote interface`

I am trying to use the `--enable-lazy-frame-loading` startup parameter, And give the iframe a `loading = "eager"` but it doesn't work.

The problem caused:

1. Iframe will not load under inactive tab
2. The timer is not accurate
3. There may be other issues

Comment: Try setting `chrome://flags/#expensive-background-timer-throttling` to "Disabled" as well as other flags that show up when searching for "timer" or "background" or "throttle".

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.